# What is the more concise way to structure this if/else statement in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following statement in a Rails project, but there has to be a more compact way to write it:

```
<% if current_user.present? %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_artist_path(artist) %>
<% end %>

<% if current_user.present? && current_user.admin? %>
 | <%= link_to "delete", artist, method: :delete,
                            data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

There has to be a more compact way to express this. I thought that `if elsif end` would work but that is giving me an error. What is the better way to write this?

Comment: `current_user.admin?` expression could go inside the first `if current_user.present?`.

Comment: what about something like this
`<%= link_to "Edit", edit_artist_path(artist) if current_user.present? %>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `devise` gem to handle user sessions you can use `user_signed_in?` instead of `current_user.present?`

Lets assume that you don't, few ways to do it:

1:

```
<% if current_user.present? %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_artist_path(artist) %>
  <%= link_to "delete", artist, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } if current_user.admin? %>
<% end %>
```

2:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_artist_path(artist) if current_user.present? %>
<%= link_to "delete", artist, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } if current_user.present? && current_user.admin?%>
```

3: you can create helper method called `admin_signed_in?` that will check and return `current_user.present? && current_user.admin?`

Using devise:

1:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_artist_path(artist) %>
  <%= link_to "delete", artist, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } if current_user.admin? %>
<% end %>
```

2:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_artist_path(artist) if user_signed_in? %>
<%= link_to "delete", artist, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin?%>
```

Comment: Ok, I was wondering if there was some sort of if / then type of syntax that would be simpler. I can refactor into a helper. Makes sense thanks.